# Fixing the "DBUS-call failed" error when opening files with xdg-open

Tags: arch-linux, i3, d-bus, freedesktop

When I call `xdg-open pic.png` I get this message.

```
** (ristretto:7580): WARNING **: 13:44:21.730: 
DBUS-call failed:GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: 
The name org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1 was not provided by any .service files
```

How can I fix this ?
Thank you for help

Comment: Do you have a thumbnailer installed? e.g. tumbler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to install a thumbnailer package. I chose [tumbler](https://archlinux.pkgs.org/rolling/archlinux-extra-x86_64/tumbler-4.16.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.html). You can install it using pacman:

```
sudo pacman -S tumbler
```

Imidietly after install everything works fine.

---

Thanks @bain for helpful comment. I would not be able to solve this without his help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having this issue, this should fix the issue

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY &
```

Comment: Why does it fix the issue?